# Javascript recursion not stopping

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function alertJson(obj){  
    if (obj === undefined) return 'undefined\n';
    if (obj === null) return 'null\n';
    for (var k in obj){     
       alert(obj[k]);
       alertJson(obj[k]);   
    }

}

alertJson({
    a: {
        complicatedly: {
            nested: ['object']
        }
    }
});
```

I have two questions...

1. Why does the alert keep on going after the fourth alert?
2. Why does it bring first `[object Object]` for first two items and then `object` alone for other two.

Comment: When you are at `['object'][0]` you will have the string `object` and you keep calling your function with `"o"` as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because it is an infinite loop since it is running the same operation on the string `"o"`, you really need to check the type before calling `alertJson`
2. Because when you `toString()` an object it returns `[object Object]` and the object by itself is the string object.

**code**

```
function alertJson(obj) {
    //if (obj === undefined) return 'undefined\n';
    //if (obj === null) return 'null\n';
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var val = obj[prop];
            console.log(val);
            if (val && typeof val === "object") {
                alertJson(val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/vcV8Y/)

OR you can use [`JSON.stringify(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're wanting to call

```
alert(k);
```

rather than

```
alert(obj[k]);
```

using alert(k) should give you:
"a" > "complicatedly" > "nested" > 0

The recursion is caused when you call alertJson passing in a string.  When this happens, you iterate over the string, and call alertJson with each character (as a 1 char string).

This fiddle should be closer to what you might expect: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKvf/

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the alert keep on going after the fourth alert?

Because you call `alertJson` on the string `'object'`. The for loop will then iterate over each character of the string, which in turn calls `alertJson` on each character. So it will call `alertJson('o')` and again `alertJson('o')` (first (and only) character of the string) and so on, since you have no exit condition for strings.

> Why does it bring first `[object Object]` for first two items and then object alone for other two.

The default string representation of objects is `[object Object]`. The one for arrays is a concatenation of their elements, and since the array has only one element, the output is `object`. The string `'object'` obviously results in the output `object`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question:

When the variable `obj[k]` the alert function calls `.toString()` on it:

```
var a = {};
console.log(a.toString()) // "[object Object]"
var a = [];
console.log(a.toString()) // ""
var a = ["1", "2", "3"];
console.log(a.toString()) // "1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Felix Kling has answered to your question very clearly. Anyway here is the updated version of your code.

```
function alertJson(obj){  
    for (var k in obj){
       if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(k))continue;
        alert(k+' : '+obj[k].toString());
        if(typeof obj[k]=='object'){alertJson(obj[k]);}
    }

}

alertJson({
    a: {
        complicatedly: {
            nested: ['object']
        }
    }
});
```

If the object doesn't have its own property, that it didn't inherit from a prototype, then we don't want that value so we skip it and loop to the next property. continue; tells the loop to continue without reading the rest of the statements in the loop

```
if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(k))continue;
```

we don't want it to loop through string objects one character at a time

```
if(typeof obj[k]=='object'){alertJson(obj[k]);}
```